# How to load URL in json result response from API server with PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

```
<?
$password = substr(md5(microtime()) , rand(0, 26) , 8);
$username = 'SAG' . $password;
$params = ['username' => $username, 'mobile' => 'yes', 'lang' => 'en', 'game_code' => 'lobby', 'page_site' => 'live'];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.gmaster8.com/BBIN/game/open",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic U0FHQVBJOjEyMzRxd2Vy"
    ) ,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:$password",
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
?>
```

I got the $result like this:

```
{"url":"https:\/\/888.gsoftbb.com\/app\/WebService\/JSON\/display.php\/Login?website=gamingsoft&uppername=dgmaster8rmb&username=C71SAGabfbbcc9&lang=en-us&page_site=live&page_present=live&key=t7ksrtefa9e54610003dfb2b05986de7fcfa6btsmtpho&"}
```

How can I post the API and then load the url in response from API server? What code should I replace the line

```
echo $result;
```

to load the url in json response from API server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this where you have echo $result

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
header("Location: {$result['url']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
[...]
$ json = json_decode ($ result);
print_r ($ json);
```

Or that way if you want to print in a more friendly way:

```
[...]
$ result = curl_exec ($ curl);
header ("Content-type: application / json");
$ json = json_decode ($ result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r ($ json);
```

`json_decode` transforms your string into JSON and `json_encode` transforms your JSON into a string.

`json_decode` accepts `flags`, such as `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`. See more at https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

**EDIT**

That said, if you want to redirect to the URL returned in JSON, instead of printing the returned value, just do the following:

```
[...]
$ result = curl_exec ($curl);
$ json = json_decode ($result);
header("Location: {$result['url']}");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I follow your code but it still only print the result in array with beatiful format: but the page not forward or reload to open URL in json.

Comment: I follow your code but it still only print the result in array with beatiful format `Array ( [url] => https://888.gsoftbb.com/app/WebService/JSON/display.php/Login?website=gamingsoft&uppername=dgmaster8rmb&username=C71SAGbc8b93ff&lang=en-us&page_site=live&page_present=live&key=ieiviz7c6ba0db174d9d828db5bbec2c23acc0aglzbdb& )` but not open that URL.

Comment: I have try with replace function and I can handle it now

`<?
........
$result = str_replace('\/','/',curl_exec($curl));
$result = str_replace('{"url":"','',$result);
$result = str_replace('"}','',$result);
?>
<a href="<? echo $result; ?>" target="_blank">OPEN URL</a>`